# Can not find library valkka

Tags: python, camera, zeep

I try to use this library to control my ptz cameras https://elsampsa.github.io/valkka-examples/_build/html/index.html instead of https://github.com/FalkTannhaeuser/python-onvif-zeep. In tutorial page, https://elsampsa.github.io/valkka-examples/_build/html/onvif.html
I see the next example:

```
from valkka.onvif import OnVif, getWSDLPath
```

but I can't find valkka library in the pypy.

How I can set up this library to my venv?

Comment: Compile and install it manually with your virtual environment loaded. The process is described on the GitHub page. Though I must say that it's not particularly good, since it insinuates the use of Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [install](https://valkka.readthedocs.io/en/latest/requirements.html) Valkka first. When you are using Ubuntu, then you can use `apt-get` to install it. Otherwise you have to [build libValkka and the python bindings yourself](https://github.com/elsampsa/valkka-core#compile-yourself).